# Unable to use custom dataset: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python-3.x, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to train a classification model with a custom dataset using Huggingface Transformers, but I keep getting errors. Last error seems solvable but I somehow I do not understand how.
What am I doing wrong?

I encode data with

```
model_name = "dbmdz/bert-base-italian-uncased"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, do_lower_case = True)

def encode_data(texts):
    return tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
                texts, 
                add_special_tokens=True, 
                return_attention_mask=True, 
                padding = True,
                truncation=True,
                max_length=200,
                return_tensors='pt'
            )
```

Then I create my datasets with

```
import torch

class my_Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings, labels):
        self.encodings = encodings
        self.labels = torch.tensor(labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        item = {key: val[idx] for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        item['labels'] = self.labels[idx]
        print(item)
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)
```

So I have

```
encoded_data_train = encode_data(df_train['text'].tolist())
encoded_data_val = encode_data(df_val['text'].tolist())
encoded_data_test = encode_data(df_test['text'].tolist())
dataset_train = my_Dataset(encoded_data_train, df_train['labels'].tolist())
dataset_val = my_Dataset(encoded_data_val, df_val['labels'].tolist())
dataset_test = my_Dataset(encoded_data_test, df_test['labels'].tolist())
```

Then I initiate my Trainer with

```
from transformers import AutoConfig, TrainingArguments, DataCollatorWithPadding, Trainer

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='/trial',
    learning_rate=1e-6,
    do_train=True,
    do_eval=True,
    evaluation_strategy='epoch',
    num_train_epochs=10,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    warmup_steps=0,
    weight_decay=0.2,
    logging_dir="./logs",
)

num_labels = len(label_dict)
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(model_name,num_labels = num_labels)

trainer = Trainer(
  model=model,
  args=training_args,
  data_collator=DataCollatorWithPadding(tokenizer),
  tokenizer= tokenizer,
  train_dataset=dataset_train,
  eval_dataset=dataset_val,
)
```

and finally I train

```
trainer.train()
```

Here is the error I get

```
AttributeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5d018b4b061d> in <module>
----> 1 trainer.train()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/trainer.py in train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, **kwargs)
   1032             self.control = self.callback_handler.on_epoch_begin(self.args, self.state, self.control)
   1033 
-> 1034             for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
   1035 
   1036                 # Skip past any already trained steps if resuming training

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    433         if self._sampler_iter is None:
    434             self._reset()
--> 435         data = self._next_data()
    436         self._num_yielded += 1
    437         if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    473     def _next_data(self):
    474         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 475         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    476         if self._pin_memory:
    477             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]
---> 47         return self.collate_fn(data)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/data/data_collator.py in __call__(self, features)
    116 
    117     def __call__(self, features: List[Dict[str, Union[List[int], torch.Tensor]]]) -> Dict[str, torch.Tensor]:
--> 118         batch = self.tokenizer.pad(
    119             features,
    120             padding=self.padding,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py in pad(self, encoded_inputs, padding, max_length, pad_to_multiple_of, return_attention_mask, return_tensors, verbose)
   2558         if self.model_input_names[0] not in encoded_inputs:
   2559             raise ValueError(
-> 2560                 "You should supply an encoding or a list of encodings to this method"
   2561                 f"that includes {self.model_input_names[0]}, but you provided {list(encoded_inputs.keys())}"
   2562             )

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

What I am doing wrong?
I also tried using

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset

dataset_train = TensorDataset(encoded_data_train['input_ids'], encoded_data_train['attention_mask'], torch.tensor(df_train['labels'].tolist()))
dataset_test = TensorDataset(encoded_data_test['input_ids'], encoded_data_test['attention_mask'], torch.tensor(df_test['labels'].tolist()))
dataset_val = TensorDataset(encoded_data_val['input_ids'], encoded_data_val['attention_mask'], torch.tensor(df_val['labels'].tolist()))
```

getting the same error. I am using torch == 1.7.1 and transformers == 4.4.2

EDIT FOLLOWING FIRST COMMENT.
Here is an example of 5-dimensional `encoded_data_train`

```
{'input_ids': tensor([[  102,   927,  9534, 30936,  2729, 29505,   123, 11805,  7427, 10587,
          9703,   927,  9534, 30936,  2719, 10118,  2321,   784,   366,   113,
          3627,  7763,  9433,   223,   148, 30937,  4051,  3400,  4011, 20005,
          6079,   784,   366,  7809, 11967,   192,  3497,   784,   366,  7809,
         11967,   192,  3497,   784,   366,  7809, 11967,   192,  3497,   784,
           366,  7809, 11967,   192,  3497,   714,   927,  9534, 30936,  2729,
         29505,   123, 11805,  7427,   260,   480,  1556,   152,  7113, 20734,
           151,   143,   784,   366,   113,  3627,  7763, 19638,   159,  1233,
          1674,  5442,   119,  9433,   223,   148, 30937,   135,   642,   829,
          2250,   223,   743,   151,   143, 14572, 13799,  1767, 28915, 12057,
         12342,   784,   366,   113,  9703,   927,  9534, 30936,  9480, 10125,
          8418,  3726,  8379,  2955,   119,  1006, 30946,  8897,   123,  6423,
           115,  1601,   544, 30938,  3013,   160, 30941,   137,   124, 14118,
         30936,   193,  2701, 19214,  1457,  2701,  1864,   409, 19727, 13305,
          6423,   115, 10389, 13908,   127,  4092, 14079,  1601,  2009, 24286,
         23419,   103],
        [  102, 10587,  2130,   182,  8022,  2719, 10118,   132, 30976, 30943,
         17961,  5123,  3292,  3627, 11532,  2719, 10118,   132, 30976, 30943,
         17961,  5123,  3292,  3627, 11532,  2719, 10118,   201, 17961,  5123,
          3292,  3627, 11532,  6354,   480,  1556, 28951, 17586,   113, 12699,
           135,   480,  1556,  7347,   677,   135,  3110,   103,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0],
        [  102,  2719, 10118,  6729,  6530, 10754, 11752, 10272, 11752,   119,
          4200,   209, 30944, 19919,  2201,  5754,   642,   838, 15657,  6156,
         30941,   148, 30937,  2201,  7305,   642,  6331,  3348, 30937,   170,
           148, 30937,  2463,   103,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0],
        [  102,   780, 30938, 18834,  2336,  2719, 10118,  8823,   784,   366,
           113,   135,  1543,  2080,  1233, 20734,   316,  1767,  1542,  2771,
           152, 25899,   119,  8823,   119,  4472,   784,   366,   113,   137,
          1031,   510,  7763,   123, 21478,  3200,   111,   985,   119,  1670,
          4999,   290, 30941,   119,  6951, 12042,   106,  1542,   135,   245,
         30942, 26609,   199,   983,   119,   261, 28040,  8142,   148, 30937,
           150,   143,   917,  1621,  7161,   111, 26609,  8217,  3723, 12510,
           290, 30941,   119,  8886, 30934,  9798,   106,   204, 30942,  5807,
           155,  1176,   213, 12057,   189,   387,  4953,   214,  2643,  4429,
           123, 11224,  3096,   193,   143,  8823,   387,  2353,  2009,   193,
           982,   176, 18789,   299,  8292,   553,  9798,  8886, 30934, 20853,
           490,  4802, 19222,   642,  3829,  1455, 26321,   167,   148, 30937,
         11498,   123,   103,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0],
        [  102, 10587,   491,  5462,  7664, 22790,  2719, 10118,  8498,   408,
         24484,   112,   491,  5462,  7664, 22790,  3671,   135,   341,  1011,
           299, 18239,   113,   143,   575,  8498,   265,   669,   113,  3850,
         16465,   480,   283, 28951,   810, 21223,   103,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
             0,     0]]), 'token_type_ids': tensor([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]), 'attention_mask': tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])}
```

and accordingly the result of `dataset_train.__getitem__(0)`

```
{'input_ids': tensor([  102,   927,  9534, 30936,  2729, 29505,   123, 11805,  7427, 10587,
         9703,   927,  9534, 30936,  2719, 10118,  2321,   784,   366,   113,
         3627,  7763,  9433,   223,   148, 30937,  4051,  3400,  4011, 20005,
         6079,   784,   366,  7809, 11967,   192,  3497,   784,   366,  7809,
        11967,   192,  3497,   784,   366,  7809, 11967,   192,  3497,   784,
          366,  7809, 11967,   192,  3497,   714,   927,  9534, 30936,  2729,
        29505,   123, 11805,  7427,   260,   480,  1556,   152,  7113, 20734,
          151,   143,   784,   366,   113,  3627,  7763, 19638,   159,  1233,
         1674,  5442,   119,  9433,   223,   148, 30937,   135,   642,   829,
         2250,   223,   743,   151,   143, 14572, 13799,  1767, 28915, 12057,
        12342,   784,   366,   113,  9703,   927,  9534, 30936,  9480, 10125,
         8418,  3726,  8379,  2955,   119,  1006, 30946,  8897,   123,  6423,
          115,  1601,   544, 30938,  3013,   160, 30941,   137,   124, 14118,
        30936,   193,  2701, 19214,  1457,  2701,  1864,   409, 19727, 13305,
         6423,   115, 10389, 13908,   127,  4092, 14079,  1601,  2009, 24286,
        23419,   103]), 'token_type_ids': tensor([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]), 'attention_mask': tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), 'labels': tensor(5)}
```

Comment: Can you please add a small example of `encodings` and `labels` (like 5) and check if `mydataset` with these 5 examples throws an error?

Comment: @cronoik . I updated the question with what you asked. I do get the same error with that 5 samples.

Comment: My situation was similar to yours but not the same. I solved my issue by putting print statements just above the line that broke. See your /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/tokenization_utils_base.py and print out the booleans and especially encoded_inputs. I was surprised what was being passed as encoded inputs, and it ended up being because I didn't set eval_dataset=my_dataset, so the first parameter predict() got it thought was a torch.Dataset. Your situation will be different, but the above still may be revealing

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the `__getitem__` function.
As you see in `dataset_train.__getitem__(0)` we get the dictionary with inputids
and all other keys. The below fix worked for me:

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        input_ids = torch.tensor(self.encodings['input_ids'])
        target_ids = torch.tensor(self.labels[idx])
        return {"input_ids": input_ids, "labels": target_ids}
```